# iframe resizing with scrollheight in chrome/safari

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, resize

I'm trying to resize (make bigger or smaller) an iframe based on it's contents. After a click on each page a method is called which does the resizing.

In Chrome I can make the iframe bigger, but not smaller. document.body.scrollHeight is always the biggest value.

So if one big page sets #iframe.height = '620px', and someone clicks on a link to page with less content scrollHeight will remain at 620px instead of decreasing.

What's the proper way of handling this in Chrome/Safari?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Before you ask for the height of the document inside the iframe you should set the height of the iframe object to "auto". Something like this:

```
objIframe = document.getElementById('theIframeId');    
objIframe.style.height = 'auto';
```

And now:

```
document.body.scrollHeight
```

returns the actual height of the document.

Comment: Brilliant! Have been fighting with this for days!

Comment: If anyone else comes across this, what fixed it for me is setting 'document.body.scrollHeight' for Firefox, and 'document.documentElement.scrollHeight' for Chrome and anything else... My example uses postMessage for cross domain

`if(isFirefox) {
    e.source.postMessage('height:' + document.body.scrollHeight, e.origin);
   } else {
    e.source.postMessage('height:' + document.documentElement.scrollHeight, e.origin);
   }`

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I've included it in my iFrame library https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer

Comment: @nitsuj just curious, how did you go about deciding which message to listen to or to send (body.scrollHeight vs. documentElement.scrollHeight) in a given browser?

Comment: in my case not iframe but the inner `div` needed to be `height:auto`

Answer (score 11):

Did you try using `document.documentElement.scrollHeight` instead?

Comment: If your iFrame is too large, this won't won't shrink to hug your content.

Answer (score 0):

According to spec, `Element.scrollHeight` will round the value to an integer. If you need an accurate fractional value, use `Element.getBoundingClientRect()` instead.