# How to set the height of an iframe pointing to Orbeon Forms to match the height if its content

Tags: orbeon

I have a form built with Form Builder. I am showing the form in an `iframe`. How can I calculate the forms height so I can pass it to the `iframe` and as result have no vertical scroll bar on the `iframe` but only on the main window.

I tried calling this  method on onload event of the `iframe`:

```
function setSize() {
    var iFrame = document.getElementById("myIframe");
    if (iFrame.contentDocument) {
      //FF 3.0.11, Opera 9.63, and Chrome
      iFrame.height = iFrame.contentDocument.documentElement.scrollHeight + 30; 
    } else {
      //IE6, IE7 and Chrome
      iFrame.height = iFrame.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 30;
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work because the content of the `iframe` isn't ready yet (if I call the method on button click everything works fine). Is their another way to achieve this? Is their an event when the form is fully initialized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question doesn't need to depend on the particular technology used to generate the content if the `iframe` (Orbeon Forms in your case). So I would refer you to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934323/iframe-height) and in particular [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2401257/5295) that uses jQuery.

Comment: Thank you for answering, this worked fine form me :                $('myIframe').load(function() {
this.style.height =     this.contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight + 30 + 'px';
        });

Comment: Excellent, I am glad this helped. And the credit should got to @Tom who provided the answer using jQuery in that other thread. Could you mark this question as answered, by clicking on the 'v' to the left of the answer above?