# Resizing body height after iframe change src

Tags: php, html, iframe, resize, onclick

So I automatically resize my iframe based on content height as follows:

```
<a href="#" onClick="sc.style.height='200px'; window.location.reload(); window.open('19.htm', 'middle'); return false;">Link1</a>
<iframe src="19.htm" name="middle"  id="middle" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

However, I use my methods of resizing body haven't worked...

I try the above code to automatically resize the body height so the iframe fit easily in the page because different pages content have different height

Any suggestions?

Comment: What did you try and what didn't work?

Comment: actually i am new in these type of coding 
and my English is also weak
sorry :(

Comment: Yeah, so? What did you try so far?

Comment: @SergeiTulentsev i edited my question 
and my dear friend i believe on this try again and again until you achieve success

Comment: you want to change to body height of the main page, or the iframe? or do you want to change the size of the iframe itself?

Comment: @MrGlass i want to change the body size so the iframe is adjusted with out showing scroll

Comment: is there any short and easy way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following link contains the info you need: [Control iframe height with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934323/iframe-height)

It's worth using jQuery to make the dynamic changes you'll need. In particular...

- http://api.jquery.com/height/
- http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2010/02/dynamically-create-iframe-with-jquery.html

If you've not used jQuery before now's the time to start. It makes life *much* easier.