# iframe inside div cut off content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

i have an iframe inside a div. the thing is, the iframe have an expanding menu (expands vertically) inside it. so, the height of the iframe will be dynamic, depending on what item is expanded. when i expand it, it will cut off and not show. below is the code for the div and the iframe.

```
 <div class="camera">
<iframe name="ifra" id="ifra"  title ="iframe" src="pages/whitef.html" frameBorder=0 scrolling="no"></iframe>
</div>
```

this is the css for both item.

```
iframe#ifra{
position: relative;
width: 810px;
min-height: 750px;
height:100%;
margin-top: -40px;
z-index: 1;
border:none;
overflow:hidden;
}
.camera {
height: 100%;
}
```

what i want to achieve is that the iframe will expand according to the expanded menu and also not being cut off.

Comment: can you add a jsfiddle example

Comment: Instead of iframe have you tried JQuery load() method or post method. That might help you.

Comment: here http://jsfiddle.net/T3yJU/ . i want to make it so that when user expands the menu, the iframe and div expands with it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mHs45/ - I just added width: 100% to the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is in your CSS,

you may write this

```
overflow-y:scroll; //that will create a scroll in the iframe the content will not be hidden,
```

while you write `OVERFLOW: HIDDEN;` it will take the contenr increase in overflow and will cut down, will not shown.

Edit : for new link

Refer Old conversation for the same

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/934323/control-iframe-height-with-jquery`

that will do :)

Comment: i do not want scrollbars in it. thats why i hidden the overflow.

Comment: then please verify the height approximation and use the `height:???px` as `height:100%` will not help here. thank you,

Comment: i want the i frame to follow the size since i have expanding menu inside of the iframe. so, setting the max height is okay, but it will leave a lot of space if the menu is collapsed.

Comment: @ShazeryNasir I think this will help, refer the link of old conversation, `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/934323/control-iframe-height-with-jquery` here see the second answer with function by "Jose Basilio". I hope that will do. :)

Answer (score 0):

ok [this](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/iframessi2.htm) plug-in is out there to do what you requested, but it works only if the iframe src is in your domain.

there is also an [article](http://css-tricks.com/cross-domain-iframe-resizing/) on css tricks you might want to look at.

Comment: @ShazeryNasir there is not much else i could find about this. it is not a trivial thing to solve.

Comment: @ShazeryNasir also have a look at this https://github.com/premasagar/appleofmyiframe